# Create user to protect data from copy / send / upload

Tags: networking, usb, permissions, internet

We want to present non-public (but not sensitive) data to our customers in a reading room, where we have Ubuntu PCs running, connected to the internet. One idea is now to create a user on these systems that has access to the data (can view it) on screen. But USB ports and internet access must be blocked, so there is no way a customer can copy or send the data to some storage.

Is there a manageable way to do this? We would of course need to upload / copy the data to some directory, but then lock it so no other user has access to it, except the one with "exits closed".

Technical how-tos are appreciated, as well as hints to software that would help to manage it.

Comment: Search this site (and the internet) for "Kiosk mode". This may be exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I was after that already. Maybe I lack some basic understanding, but the how-tos on kiosk mode are: How to turn your Ubuntu machine to an (internet) kiosk with a browser.

Maybe more specific: I want to login to a user, and that user only has access to a few folders with data (images, pdf, text), and be able to view that